# How to integrate with given substitution?

Tags: integration, substitution

Using the substitution $u = x^2e^{-4x} + 3$, find $$\int\frac{x(1-2x)}{x^2+3e^{4x}} dx$$

Comment: **You** are supposed to find it or, at least, show your working and explain where you are stuck. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$I\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int\frac{x(1-2x)}{x^2+3e^{4x}}\:dx=\int\frac{xe^{-4x}(1-2x)}{x^2e^{-4x}+3}\:dx=\int\frac{du}{2u}=\frac{1}{2}\ln{|u|}+C$$
where $u = x^2e^{-4x}+3$.